# Django: Multiple table Model query

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm, qobject

I have tried it on the Q object and in the Django ORM but could not generate the query.

```
class Status(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.AutoField(null=True, max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        
class Billing(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.AutoField(null=True, max_length=1000)
    sr_number = models.AutoField(null=True, max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        
class BillingInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    billings = models.ForeignKey(Billing, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    net_amount = models.AutoField(null=True, max_length=100)
    company = models.AutoField(null=True, max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.company
        
class BillingOutput(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    billing_infos = models.ForeignKey(BillingInfo, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    lbl_name = models.AutoField(null=True, max_length=100)
    lbl_qty = models.AutoField(null=True, max_length=100)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.lbl_name
```

I required an equivalent ORM Query for the below raw SQL query:

```
select bio.* from billing bil
    inner join billing_infos bi on bil.id = bi.billings_id
    inner join billing_output bio on bi.id = bio.billing_infos_id
    where bo.status_id = 1
    order by bio.id desc;
```

Could someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: what is `bo.status_id`? You did not specify a table `bo`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`.select_related(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to retrieve the related `billing_infos` and `billing` of that `billing_infos`:

```
BillingOutput.objects.select_related(
    'billing_infos__billing'
).filter(status_id=1, billing_infos__billing__isnull=False).order_by('-id')
```

---

> **Note**: Django will add by default an [**`AutoField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#autofield) as `primary_key=True` to a model with name `id` if you do not specify a primary key yourself, so there is no need to explicitly declare a primary key.

Comment: Thanks, @willem-van-onsem.
I want to fetch ***billing_infos*** table data also. Is that possible?

`
select bio.*, bi.* from billing bil
    inner join billing_infos bi on bil.id = bi.billings_id
    inner join billing_output bio on bi.id = bio.billing_infos_id
    where bo.status_id = 1
    order by bio.id desc;
`

Comment: The above query is left outer join, For an inner join what do I need to change in the ORM.

Comment: @selva316: nothing, the `__isnull=False` will eventually produce the same result since it filters out `NULL`s constructed by a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. The Django ORM can sometimes optimize this slightly.

Comment: Thanks, @Willem. I want to add conditions for billing_infos.company='XXX'. Is there any other way to add a where clause for another table?

Comment: @selva316: yes, add `billing_infos__company='XXX'` in the `filter(..)` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do this :

```
qry1 = "select bio.* from billing bil
            inner join billing_infos bi on bil.id = bi.billings_id
            inner join billing_output bio on bi.id = bio.billing_infos_id
            where bo.status_id = 1
            order by bio.id desc;" 
bio = Billing.objects.raw(qry1 , [user_id])
```